# How to put a list in session and use it inside Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, session, servlets

I have a list of notification messages which I extract from the databse and put in the session in a servlet. This is then forwarded to a jsp page using `requesDipstacher.forward(request,response`). I now take the List of messages and loop it through using jstl :

```
<c:foreach value = "item" items = '${sessionScope.notification}'>
   <a href = "javascript:printAll('${item}'}>Print</a>
</c:foreach>
```

The javascript looks like this

```
function printAll(item)
{  
  display(item) //note this is pseudo code . Here I kind of display the items.
}
```

Now my problem is there are far too many links displaying `print` in my webpage. I want to send the whole list into the javascript and iterate over it and display the individual messages. Is this possible with javascript.Kindly point me to an identical question if it exists.

Comment: you mean, you dont want to show print many times?? then when you want to show that notification message?? please let us know what you want, much clearer way?

Comment: It should happen on just one clik ...I just want  one hyperlink to take the whole list to javascript where I want to loop through it and display the notifications.

Comment: item is just the value which the list contsins at that iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have problem with put the *javascript* in the same file of the page, you could put something like this:

```
<script>
function printAll()
{
  var html = '<ul>';
  <c:foreach value = "item" items = '${sessionScope.notification}'>
    html += '<li>${item}</li>';
  </c:foreach>
  html += '</ul>';
  display(html);
}
</script>

<a href = "javascript:printAll();">Print</a>
```

As you notice it, there are various ways to solve the problem.